# memcache won't appear php with osx homebrew

Tags: php, macos, apache, homebrew

I have php project I want to develop in osx and I have used memcache

I have implemented in linux but when I try to migrate to osx i can't find memcache

I have tried to install it with brew or pecl doesn't work

I have tried xampp as well and doesn't work

> Sure I have done
>
> ```
>  sudo apachectl restart
> ```
>
> > added memcache.co to php.ini

I use php 5.6 and php 7.0 and just note I use memcache not memcached

Answer (score 0):

It should be installed with PECL:

```
pecl install memcache
```

locate the php.ini file:

```
php --ini
```

then edit the php.ini file and add the complete path to memcache.so (as shown at the end of the installation output)

Comment: I have done already by using  `pecl` and added the path before post the question and didn't work as well